# How to create a UIViewController layout in storyboard and then use it in code?

Tags: iphone, ios5, modalviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a Storyboard in my iOS 5 application.

In there I have created a number of screens and it works perfectly.

However there's one view controller that I create in code, not as a result of UI action but at the end of processing data. I would like to show this view controller then, as a modalViewController, but also have it designed in the storyboard editor.

Is it possible? Using the nibs I did it like this:

```
ResultsController *rc = [[ResultsController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ResultsController"
                                                            bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:rc animated:YES];
[rc release];
```

Right now I don't really have a nib files, so how do I do it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Take a look at the UIStoryboard class. There is a instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier Method. So you need to set the Identfier within the Storyboard Editor for your ResultsController ViewController.

You can do something like this

```
UIViewController *viewController = 
   [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" 
                              bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ResultsController"];

[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks! And... is there a way to set a button that would dismissModalViewController directly on the storyboard? Without attaching it to a method in code that only calls this dismiss... method?

Comment: I don't think it works without code, because there's no connection to any other ViewControllers within the Storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

In your storyboard:

1. Add a generic UIViewController.
2. With the Identity Inspector, set its custom class as your ResultsController.
3. Create a modal segue from your source view controller to the ResultsController

Answer (score 2):

For **Swift 4**

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ResultsController")
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```