# How do I create storyboard segue from a view controller to itself?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

Is it possible to create a storyboard segue from a view controller to itself? I have a bunch of Entities that have Related Entities. I'd like to be able to display a Related Entity using the same view controller that's displaying the Entity. But I can't seem to create a segue that will display a new instance of the origin view controller.

Is it just not allowed? Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well here's a solution that isn't quite the same but gets me what I want. I found it as an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111218/how-to-create-a-uiviewcontroller-layout-in-storyboard-and-then-use-it-in-code).

The reason I thought I had to use a segue rather than the good old programmatic push of a view controller onto the navigation controller's stack is that I had set up the view controller's IBOutlets in the storyboard. I didn't realize that you could create a copy of the view controller as laid out in the storyboard without using a storyboard segue. You can! To see how to do it, check out that other question and up vote the answerer!

Comment: I gave you two ups because, even tough nobody answered, you find yourself the solution and care to publish it to help others. That's the spirit!!

Answer (score 3):

You can ctrl-click-drag (or right-click-drag) from an element (`UIButton`, etc.) to the containing view controller.

(Did you try this? I'm doing it right now; I have one stock `UIViewController` that just keeps adding itself indefinitely to the containing `UINavigationController` stack via a normal `push` segue.)

Comment: This is good but you can't drag from the ViewController to itself in the event that you want a segue you can call programmatically.

Comment: You should still be able to name the segue (the `Identifier` field in the attributes inspector) in the storyboard editor and reference it via `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` on your `UIViewController` in code.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's annoying I can't do a 'manual' segue to itself.

What I did was added a UIButton to my view and gave it an action of push to the same view controller, and then made this button hidden. Then I can name the segue and reference it in the code.

Hacky, but works.

Comment: Indeed hacky, but I see no other solution since I have a custom segue. The accepted (referred) answer uses the default push animation, which is not what I want. I feel dirty now I've done this :x +1 nonetheless.