# iphone uiviewcontroller not displaying?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2

I am new to iphone development with objective C and XCode 4.2.  Right now I successfully instantiated a UITableViewController and it can traverse a multi level json data tree.  however, I'm having trouble establish the UI for the leaf page.  Let me show you a snippet of code so far:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        int row = [indexPath row];
        NSString * currentrow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.",row];


        NSDictionary * item = [dataArray objectForKey:currentrow];
        NSDictionary * children = [item objectForKey:@"children"];
        if(children != nil)
        {
            uinavTableViewController *childView = [[uinavTableViewController alloc] init];
            childView.dataArray = children;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:childView animated:YES]; 
        }
        else
        {
            uinavMenuItem * childView = [[uinavMenuItem alloc] init];
            //uinavSecondViewController * childView = [[uinavSecondViewController alloc] init];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:childView animated:YES]; 
        }
}
```

So the first part of the if statement will check if there are children nodes, if so create another uinavTableViewController.  This part works perfectly.

The else statement creates a leaf page using the uinavMenuItem.  When I run this in the simulator, the leaf page is just a black screen.  I looked in my NSLog and can confirm that the uinavMenuItem viewDidLoad did get fired.  So the controller code is working fine, but i just don't know how to link up to the view I've drawn in the storyboard.

What am I doing wrong that prevents the uinavMenuItem from displaying what I've drawn in the storyboarD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to init a view controller you made in the storyboard, use `UIStoryboard`'s `-instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`. You define this identifier in the storyboard under the view controller's properties. Your view is loaded but empty because it's not loading what you have in the storyboard. It's probably calling `-loadView` because it cannot find one.

Here's where you enter the identifier:

[image: Enter the identifier here]

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate on "define identifier in the storyboard under view controller's properties"?   I'm taking a look around the Xcode panels but can't pinpoint something tha tlooks like instantiateViewContollerWithIdentifier

Comment: Ok, i made the identifier.  then I replaced my else statement with this:             `uinavMenuItem *childView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menuleafsegue"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:childView animated:YES];`   Is taht along the right lineS?  Right now simulator doesn't go to my uinavMenuItem.

Comment: clicking on the record that's supposed to take me ot the uinavMenuItem prints teh following statement in the debugarea: "Application tried to push a nil view controller on target"

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. If the view controller is nil, it's not finding the view controller with the identifier you specified. Try resetting the simulator/uninstall app on device to make sure your storyboard is up to date. Also make sure self.storyboard is not nil.

Comment: hmm...still no effect.  Am I supposed to have smoe kind of segue/line/relationship between my uinavMenuItem and uinavTableViewController (or the uinavNavigationController)?

Comment: No, the segue is used when you want the view push to be handled automatically. Either that or you use -didSelectRowAtIndexPath:. In this case you're doing the latter.

Comment: OK, I wasn't getting the right handle on the storyboard.  So here's what I put in the else statement:             `UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            
            uinavMenuItem *childView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menuleaf"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:childView animated:YES];`  Now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard, it is easier to just create a segue from the UITableViewController to the leaf controller. You can do this by control-clicking the table view controller and then dragging the push segue to the leaf controller. Within the X-Code sidebar, give the segue and identifier.

Then in your code, instead of calling `[self.navigationController pushViewController]` you can use:

```
if(children != nil)
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"YourIdentifierHere" sender: self];
}
else
{ 
    [self [performSegueWithIdentifier: @"TheOtherIdentifier" sender: self];
}
```

To pass data to the uinavTableViewController, you use the `prepareForSegue` method in the same controller that performs the segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender: (id)sender
{
    // Because you have two segues, you need to check the identifier
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"YourIdentifierHere"])
    {
        uinavTableViewController childView = (uinavTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        childView.dataArray = children;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i can't figure out howto give the segue an identifier.  I tried ctrl+clicking a few thigns in the right sidebar of xcode, but i didn't notice anything obviously related to segue identifiers

Comment: First control-click your table view controller, then under "Storyboard Segues", drag the circle next to "Push" to the leaf controller. Storyboard will create an arrow between the controllers (this is the segue). Click on the arrow (or the icon in the middle of the arrow) and open the attribute inspector (XCode's right sidebar, fourth tab from the left, looks like a belt buckle) and then edit "Identifier".

Comment: thanks.  Now when I run the simulator ,I get a SIGABRT error.  So I guess this is a memory error or i didn't instantiate somethign properly?

Comment: I updated my code with a little more detail... try that. You should have two segues defined, one to uinavTableViewController (if children is not nil) and one to uinavMenuItem (if children is nil). In my example "YourIdentifierHere" is the former, "TheOtherIdentifier" is the latter.

Comment: in my storyboard, i have just 1 uinavTableViewController.  I tried to drag a segue onto itself, but Xcode won't let me do it ,the segue just snaps back or it crashes my Xcode.  The uinavtableviewcontroller already has one push segue to a uinavigationcontoller, if that makes any difference.  This uinavtableviewcontroller class is re-used for each branch of json data.

Comment: I see. You should use Plenilune's answer then. There is a similar question/answer here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111218/how-to-create-a-uiviewcontroller-layout-in-storyboard-and-then-use-it-in-code