# How to segue to same controller from different view?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have a tab view controller with a few tabs.  One tab leads to the "players" view through a navigation controller. A second tab leads to a "settings" view.  The settings view has a button to select a "default" player and so it tries to segue to the players view through a separate navigation controller.

Diagram:

```
Players Tab -> Navigation Controller "A" -> Players View Controller
Settings Tab -> Navigation Controller "B" (w/named segue) -> Players View Controller
```

The Players tab view does not have a "named" segue as it has a relationship to the tab controller.  The settings tab navigation controller has a named segue.

However, now when I select the "players" tab the view is empty!  The navigation bar at the top is there with the tabs but that's it. As a test, I removed the relationship from Nav "B" to Players View and now the Players tab is working once again.

I am missing a fundamental issue here but I don't know what.

Any ideas whatsoever is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question with the answer I needed.

[How to create a UIViewController layout in storyboard and then use it in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111218/how-to-create-a-uiviewcontroller-layout-in-storyboard-and-then-use-it-in-code)

Here is the relevant code:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ResultsController"];
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

I'm new to storyboards and so I was not aware that this method exists. This method solves the problem I described above. I was initially trying to segue through a navigation controller to a view that already had an established segue. With the solution here I can simply instantiate an existing view using an identifier.

I still think there should be a way to try another segue so that "perform segue" can be used.  However, I am moving forward once again.